# Adding Calculated Fields Together

Tags: sql-server

For the Case Statement that is adding together two calculated fields, I need to suppress results that render anything less than 0.  Essentially, if the Case Statement produces anything less than $0, then suppress, Else give me the number:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         @intMonth AS strMONTH
       , @intYEAR AS strYEAR
       , 'LN' AS ApplID
       , lhmt.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS AccountNbr
       , COUNT(lhmt.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS NbrofFees
       , 'Payoff Quote Fee' AS Description

       ,CASE
              WHEN lhmt.TRANSACTION_CODE_1 = 65 AND lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1 >0 THEN SUM(lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1) 
              ELSE 0
              END
             -

          CASE
              WHEN lhmt.TRANSACTION_CODE_1 = 46 AND lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1 >0 THEN SUM(lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1) 
              ELSE 0
              END AS TotalFees 


FROM dbo.T_LOAN_HISTORY_MONETARY_TRANS lhmt
```

Comment: `WHEN lhmt.TRANSACTION_CODE_1 IN (46, 65) AND lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1 > 0 THEN SUM(lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1) 
`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I'm wanting to add the two different Case statements together, and anytime it renders anything less than $0, then suppress it.  Else, add the two Case statements together

Comment: What do you mean by "suppress it"? You cannot suppress a column unless you deal with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Also you're showing `@intMonth` and `@intYear` in the output, but there's nothing in the query that limits it to that month.

Comment: There are occasions when I add the two Case statements together that it renders a negative value, for which I'd like to "suppress" or zero out.  Anything other than a negative value.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results, this is just a word problem begging for misinterpretation.

Comment: the "@intMonth" and "@intYear" are applicable for a different/unrelated part of the query, so you can disregard

Comment: Why can’t you just wrap your query up into a common table expression and select from that cte along with a case expression against totalfees < 0 then 0 else totalfees?

Comment: That definitely sounds like it could work.  Can you show what that might look like?

Comment: @Mikej - for future reference, please consider creating a [minimal, complete, and verfiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) - it makes it easier for others to provide a great answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could simply wrap your original query into a common table expression and then select from the common table expression and include a case expression on TotalFees.

Something like

```
;With _cte as
(
SELECT DISTINCT
         @intMonth AS strMONTH
       , @intYEAR AS strYEAR
       , 'LN' AS ApplID
       , lhmt.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS AccountNbr
       , COUNT(lhmt.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS NbrofFees
       , 'Payoff Quote Fee' AS Description

       ,CASE
              WHEN lhmt.TRANSACTION_CODE_1 = 65 AND lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1 >0 THEN SUM(lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1) 
              ELSE 0
              END
             -

          CASE
              WHEN lhmt.TRANSACTION_CODE_1 = 46 AND lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1 >0 THEN SUM(lhmt.TRANS_AMT_1) 
              ELSE 0
              END AS TotalFees 


FROM dbo.T_LOAN_HISTORY_MONETARY_TRANS lhmt
)
SELECT   strMONTH
       , strYEAR
       , ApplID
       , AccountNbr
       , NbrofFees
       , Description
       ,case when TotalFees < 0 then 0 else TotalFees end as TotalFees
from _cte
```